# "vo" für "vau" der Deutlichkeit halber?

Tags: pronunciation

Die deutsche synthetische Stimme, die aus dem GPS-Navigationssystem in unserem Mietwagen kommt, spricht die Autobahnstrecke ***VR1*** auf Madeiera als "vo er eins" aus. Ich habe diese Aussprache "vo" für "vau" nie vorher gehört. Ist das üblich, und etwa vergleichbar mit der Aussprache "zwo" für zwei?

Comment: Ich habe das auch noch nie gehört.

Comment: Zwo für zwei sagt man, damit es nicht mit drei verwechselt wird. Ich wüsste nicht, womit vau verwechselt werden könnte

Comment: @infinitezero Natürnich ist das pedantisch :D

Comment: @infinitezero Und was ist ein _"GPS-Gerät"_ bitte? Ein _Navigationsassistenzsystem_ vielleicht?

Comment: @Beta Ich laufe heute eh' im _StandBy_, kein Problem ;-)

Comment: Ich hatte mal einen Leihwagen von Renault, dessen Navigationsgerät deutsche Sätze mit französischer Aussprache von sich gab. "Biegen Sie rechts ab" wurde zu "Biieh-zhönn ßi rekks app". Daraus lernte ich, dass diese Geräte nicht ganze Sätze gespeichert haben, sondern in der Tat Text Buchstabe für Buchstabe ablesen, wobei sie aber sprachspezifische Verlautungsregeln verwenden. Vielleicht ist das bei Deinem Fall mit "vo" ähnlich?

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Mein Wagen ist auch französisch (Citroën), der Navigator ist  von Tomtom. Die Stimme hat keine Akzent, und hört sich sehr deusch an.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Ich nehme mal an eine _schlampige Programmierung_ aus Kostengründen ist in solchen Fällen durchaus nicht unwahrscheinlich. Daher meine Antwort.

Comment: Und das Vo klingt wie Fo? Gibt es auch FR1, und wie klingt das? Und zur Sicherheit WR1? Bei dict.leo.org fand ich als möglichen Begriff für Schnellstraße "via rápida" - also nichts mit vo vorne - hätte ja sein können, dass es kürzere und längere Abkürzungen gibt.

Comment: @userunknown Klingt wie "fo", genau. Steht, wie du schon herausgefunden hast, für Via Rapida, eine Art Autobahn." FR" oder "WR" gibt es keine

Comment: Ich weiß nicht, warum man sich hier absichtlich dumm stellen muss. Hilft der Diskussion in keinster Weise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Es scheint also eindeutig so zu sein, dass es die Aussprachevariante "vo" (=fo) für ***V*** im Deutschen nicht gibt. Ein Vorteil mit so einer Aussprache gäbe es wohl auch nicht.  Daher müsste es hier um ein Misserfolg in der Arbeit mit der Programmierung der synthetischen Stimme handeln.

Answer (score 0):

Ich habe das für ein in **Deutsch** programmiertes Sprachausgabesystem auch noch nie gehört.

Auf *Madeira* besteht jedoch die Möglichkeit, dass ein in Portugal programmiertes Sprachausgabesystem für die Aussprache einzelner Konsonanten *v(w)o* statt *v(f)au* verwendet.

---

Schau mal [hier](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portugiesische_Sprache#Konsonanten_2) ob das weiterhilft, warum da *vo* statt *vau* verwendet wurde (korreliert mit Portugiesisch):

### [image]

Für ein Derivat einer Sprachspezifischen Programmierung passt man eventuell nicht alle Glyphen an (oder sagen wir mal man bevorzugt eine schlampige Programmierung aus *"Effizienzgründen"*).

---

Gesucht nach:

- konsonanten portugiesisch

---

> Ist das üblich, und etwa vergleichbar mit der Aussprache "zwo" für zwei?

Im Deutschen ist das nicht üblich.

Wie in [infinitezero's Kommentar](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/55881/vo-f%c3%bcr-vau-der-deutlichkeit-halber#comment137035_55881) erwähnt, wird *"zwo"* zur besseren akustischen Unterscheidung von *"drei"* verwendet.

Was *vo* von *vau* im Deutschen unterscheiden sollte, ist mir nicht plausibel.

Comment: Ist die Autobahnstrecke Deutsch oder Portugiesisch? ;)

Comment: Ich glaube nicht dass "V" im Portugiesischen als "fo" ausgesprochen wird, sondern als "wo". Würde also die Sache nicht erklären. Außerdem ist Tomtom ein niederländisches Unternemen, und es scheint mir nicht glaubenswert, dass die Niederländer den Portugiesen überlassen hätten, die Deutsche Fassung zu programmieren. Was sagen aber die Niederländern zu "V"?

Comment: @Beta Für Niederländisch konnte ich nichts dergleichen finden. Aber die Anpassung für speziell regionale Navikarten muss nicht zwingend in den Niederlanden erstellt worden sein.

Comment: Wo ist der Zusammenhang? Hast du zumindest gelesen was du verlinkt hast?